# Replacing special characther in string with ampersand

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, special-characters, unescapestring

I have a URL which basically looks like this:

```
https://example.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout\u0026token=EC-2BF46053LU471230V
```

The URL is generated from a statement like following:

```
if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200 || (int)response.StatusCode == 201)
  {
      var res = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      var url = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPalBlueReference>(res).paypalTransaction.paypalUrl);

      return Json(Regex.Unescape(url), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

For some reason my URL contains the:

```
\u0026
```

Sign which I'm not able to get rid of even after using

```
Regex.Unescape()
```

Method... I have even tried using the

```
Replace("\u0026","&")
```

but that didn't work either...

The URL should be formatted like this:

```
https://example.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2BF46053LU471230V
```

Can someone help me out ?

Edit: the returned JSON from server looks like this:

```
"https://example.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout\u0026token=EC-2BF46053LU471230V"
```

Edit2: This is using rokkerboci's method:

```
   if ((int)response.StatusCode == 200 || (int)response.StatusCode == 201)
        {
            var res = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var url = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPalBlueReference>(res).paypalTransaction.paypalUrl);

            return Json(url.Replace("\\u0026", "&"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The response still contains \u0026

Comment: What does the sample JSON look like?

Comment: Use this string in your replace method: Replace("\\u0026","&"). You have to escape the \ char

Comment: @rokkerboci didn't work :/

Comment: @rokkerboci edited my post at the bottom with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the **System.Web** namespace:

```
string encoded = "https://example.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout\u0026token=EC-2BF46053LU471230V";

var unencoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);

Console.WriteLine(unencoded);
```

Comment: the original URL doesn't looks like this... Wait I'll post the original URL which is shown before the Html.Decode

Comment: "https\u0026#x3a;\u0026#x2f;\u0026#x2f;www.example.com\u0026#x2f;us\u0026#x2f;cgi-bin\u0026#x2f;webscr\u0026#x3f;cmd\u0026#x3d;_express-checkout\u0026#x26;token\u0026#x3d;EC-7M752271TC172121Y"

Comment: for some reason it doesn't :( ... U can see it in my code that I'm using HTMLDecode.. I mean its just 2 lines of code, what could I've done wrong ? xD

Comment: I dont't recognize this part: \u0026#x3a; what is the #x3a?

Comment: I have no clue honestly =/

Comment: The weird part is that URL gets pretty nicely decoded when I use the Decode but I can't seem to be able to get rid of this \u0026